# servletContext Null Pointer Exception

Tags: spring, servlets, liferay, applicationcontext

I'm trying to run a liferay project on an application server, but I have to run this part of code

```
String tablesSQL = HttpUtil.URLtoString(servletContext.getResource("/WEB-INF/sql/tables.sql"));
```

The problem is that the servletContext is still null and I don't know how can I instantiate this latter using applicationContext or other stuff.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your web.xml file and please specify which application server do you use?

Comment: also where have you written this code?